# defining char datatype and and using with sprintf

Tags: c++, arduino, char, avr-gcc, avrdude

I had following setup earlier:

```
    String INSERT_SQL = "";
    // inserting to sql database on mysql server
    INSERT_SQL = "";
    INSERT_SQL.concat("INSERT INTO arduinoSensorData.sensorLog (out_temperature, out_humidity, ");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(" drwngRoom_temperature, drwngRoom_humidity, pot1_soilMoisture, pot1_avg_SoilMoisture,");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(" wateringPot1) VALUES ('");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(outdoorTempInC);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(outoorHumidity);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(indorTempinC);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(h);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(val);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(avgVal);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("', '");
    if (wateringBasedOnAlarm){
      waterMsg = "water based on alarm";

    } else waterMsg = soilMsg;
    INSERT_SQL.concat(waterMsg);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("');");
```

And later, I was converting it to char like this:

`const char *mycharp = INSERT_SQL.c_str();`

Which I realised wrong approach as in every iteration of the loop function of arduino MCU this will consume more memory!

So, I decided to change `INSERT_SQL` to char instead of declaring it as `String` at first place.

I initialised INSERT_SQL as char like this:

```
char INSERT_SQL[295];
```

Because I realised the total length would not be more than 295,

But when compiler reaches the line:

```
INSERT_SQL = "";
```

I got an error saying:

> incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [1]' to 'char [295]'

So, this is the first thing I need is to fix it and secondly, I think I cannot use `concat` with char datatype, so in that case how do I populate values to sql query using `sprintf`?

Comment: What is `which I realised wrong as in avery iteration this will consume more memory !` supposed to mean?

Comment: I realise you are wrong....Use `string` again. And `reserve` some space for better performance when appending.

Comment: Consider using [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/) instead.

Comment: @RobK  will this work https://gist.github.com/cmaglie/5883185

Comment: Naming variables in all upper case is a really bad practice. Almost every C and C++ programmer on earth will think it's a macro.

Comment: Ok cool will change it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is exactly telling you what's wrong.

```
char INSERT_SQL[295];
INSERT_SQL = "";
```

You probably want to do like:

```
char INSERT_SQL[295];
INSERT_SQL[0] = 0x00;
::strcat(INSERT_SQL, "INSERT INTO....
```

Comment: Using `::strcat(INSERT_SQL, "INSERT INTO....` what namespace `strcat` would it be using? Do I not have to be explicit?

Comment: strcat() is a standard C library function defined in string.h.  All C functions are in the global name scope.  You don't have to add "::" at the beginning, if you don't want.